# Safari on macOS Catalina - "Debugger" tab missing from developer tools?

Tags: javascript, safari, macos-catalina, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

I'm using Safari (13.1) on macOS Catalina (10.15.4) and in the Developer Tools I can't find the [`Debugger` tab](https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/safari-developer/devfce7d9aed/mac) anymore.

[image: no javascript Debugger tab in Safari 13.1 on macOS Catalina 10.15.4]

Do I need to somehow enable it? (Developer menu is enabled). Has it been (re)moved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the necessary interface inside the `Sources` tab.

Answer (score -1):

Try clicking the `+` to the right of the layers tab. Then you should be able to select the debugger and it'll open up a new debugger tab.

Comment: the only choices for a new tab are: Audit, Console, Elements, Graphics, Layers, Network, Sources, Storage, Timelines. "Debugger" does not appear.